# Books about Stohr-Voloch Theory

Tags: algebraic-curves

Can you suggest any book or lecture notes that explain the theory of Stohr-Voloch?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I am the right person to answer, as I can't judge the exposition since I kind of know the subject already. I think the original paper is quite readable. For books, you can look at:

Algebraic Curves over a Finite Field, J.W.P. Hirschfeld, G. Korchmáros, F. Torres, PUP

Algebraic Functions and Projective Curves, David Goldschmidt, Springer.

If you have any specific question, ask here on MO.